# React: State of a variable changes, but UI Icon dosen't get updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I tried creating a simple navbar that would have its buttons controlled by useState. However I have a problem where the button icon color wont update even though the state of the variable that controls it changes.

Now, I did some testing and and added text into the icon component (not show here) and made it so it was controlled by the same state as the color on the icon is now. And for some reason when I did that the state and the text inside the component both changed correctly. Could anyone provide an explanation on why that happens? Because to me it seems like I've misunderstood how react binds things to states and controls them.

Navigation bar component

```
import NavButton from "./NavButton"
import { useState } from "react";

function NavBar(){
    const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
        {id:1, name:"Orders", icon:"bx:bx-dollar-circle", active:false},
        {id:2, name:"Menu", icon:"ic:round-restaurant-menu", active:false},
        {id:3, name:"Leave", icon:"uil:exit", active:false}
        ]);

    const toggleButton = (id) => {
        setButtons(buttons.map(button => (
            button.id === id ? {...button, active:!button.active} : {...button, active:false}
        )))
    }
    return (
        <div className="h-1/6 bg-white border-b-lebo flex flex-row justify-around">
            <>
                {buttons.map((button) => (<NavButton button={button} key={button.id} onToggle={toggleButton}/>))}
            </>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

Navigation button component

```
import Icon from "./Icon";

function NavButton({button, onToggle}){
    return (
        <button onClick={() => onToggle(button.id)} className={`font-bold text-gray-500 flex flex-col items-center justify-center flex-grow w-5 hover:bg-gray-100`}>
            <p className="self-center">{button.name}</p>
            <Icon icon={button.icon} name={button.name} color={button.active ? "#454545" : "#8b8b8b"}/>
        </button>
    )
}

export default NavButton;
```

Icon component

```
function Icon({icon, color, name}) {
    return (
        <div>
        <span color={color} className="iconify h-10 w-auto self-center" data-icon={icon}></span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Icon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating 2 different Icon components.
Icon and IconDark and conditionally rendering them inside the NavButton component.
Not sure if it is the "correct" way of doing things but it got the job done.
I'm going to guess the reason why it didn't render the colors correctly earlier is because of the attribute "color" inside the component. I think JSX just took it in as another prop and did nothing with it after the first render of the element.

**edit 1:** nvm it definitely didn't get the job done. At least not well enough. The icon swap in the render isn't fast enough so it causes the user to see the icon swap.

**edit 2:** This article held the answer that I needed.

https://dev.to/abachi/how-to-change-svg-s-color-in-react-42g2

It turns out that to change an svg color with react you need to set the initial fill (or for me color) value inside the svg component to "current" and then pass the real value in from the parent element conditionally.

**Long story short** - Controlling SVG values is a little different to controlling text values in react.